# Python curses Textbox.gather() removes empty lines, is there a way to preserve them?

Tags: python, python-curses

In below code box.gather() removes empty lines from text. Is there a way to collect the text as is including empty lines?

```
from curses import wrapper
from curses.textpad import Textbox

def main(stdscr):
   stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "Enter text separated by empty lines: (hit Ctrl-G to send)")
   box = Textbox(stdscr)
   box.edit()
   return box.gather()
   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = wrapper(main)
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Textbox`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#textbox-objects) object contain [`stripspaces`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.textpad.Textbox.stripspaces) attribute which handles this behaviour.

From documentation:

### stripspaces

> This attribute is a flag which controls the interpretation of blanks
> in the window. When it is on, trailing blanks on each line are
> ignored; any cursor motion that would land the cursor on a trailing
> blank goes to the end of that line instead, and trailing blanks are
> stripped when the window contents are gathered.

So, your final code will look like this:

```py
from curses import wrapper
from curses.textpad import Textbox

def main(stdscr):
   stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "Enter text separated by empty lines: (hit Ctrl-G to send)")
   box = Textbox(stdscr)
   box.stripspaces = False
   box.edit()
   return box.gather()
   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = wrapper(main)
    print(s)
```